# Basic Java Math Test - Read variables as floats and calculate equation

Tags: java

I'm making a basic 10 question math test. Been at this for a while now and can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have 2 variables to create random numbers...

```
float firstNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);

float secondNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);
```

And a variable to create a random operator (+, -, *, /)

```
float intOperatorSymbol = (int)(Math.random()*3);

String operatorSymbol = null; 

if (intOperatorSymbol == 0)
    operatorSymbol = "+";

if (intOperatorSymbol == 1) 
    operatorSymbol = "-";

if (intOperatorSymbol == 2)
    operatorSymbol = "*";

if (intOperatorSymbol == 3)
    operatorSymbol = "/";
```

My problem is below, where I'm trying to get Java to read the number variables and operator variables as an equation and store the correct answer in a variable.

```
String correctAnswer = (firstNumber + operatorSymbol + secondNumber);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to Java (clearly.) Full code posted below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class counterTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {


// begin main loop


    for (int counter = 1; counter < 13; counter ++) {

    if (counter < 11) {

        System.out.println("Question #" + counter);

            float firstNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);

            float secondNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);

            float intOperatorSymbol = (int)(Math.random()*3);


// operator String


            String operatorSymbol = null; 

                if (intOperatorSymbol == 0)
                    operatorSymbol = "+";

                if (intOperatorSymbol == 1) 
                    operatorSymbol = "-";

                if (intOperatorSymbol == 2)
                    operatorSymbol = "*";

                if (intOperatorSymbol == 3)
                    operatorSymbol = "/";

//main arguments


        System.out.println(firstNumber + " " + operatorSymbol + " " + secondNumber);

        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userAnswer = userInputScanner.next();

        String correctAnswer = (firstNumber + operatorSymbol + secondNumber);

        System.out.println("right/wrong var here");



    } else if (counter > 11) {



// last printed line


        System.out.println("Your total score is var here");

        System.out.println(correctAnswer);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Java cannot do that. You'll need an expression parser and evaluator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the calculation in your if statements for the operator:

```
float intOperatorSymbol = (int)(Math.random()*3);
float correctAnswer = 0.0;

// operator String


            String operatorSymbol = null; 

                if (intOperatorSymbol == 0){
                    operatorSymbol = "+";
                    correctAnswer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                }
                if (intOperatorSymbol == 1) {
                    operatorSymbol = "-";
                    correctAnswer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
               }

                if (intOperatorSymbol == 2){
                    operatorSymbol = "*";
                    correctAnswer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                }

                if (intOperatorSymbol == 3){
                    operatorSymbol = "/";
                    correctAnswer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
                }
```

Comment: Nice! This is giving me bad answers for some reason though. 5.0 + 5.0 gave me correct answer of 0.555556

Comment: when you say "bad", what do you mean?

Comment: I think you are missing some braces around the `if` statements, so `correctAnswer` will always be set to `firstNumber / secondNumber`.  Also some semicolons missing as well.

Comment: I did a println of correctAnswer at the end. For each question it is giving me the wrong answer in fractions. When I ran it just now 9 * 5 was the first question to prompt. After I answered it ran println(correctAnswer) and gave me 1.8.

Comment: Thank you both a ton for your help. I really appreciate it! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class counterTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {


// begin main loop


    for (int counter = 1; counter < 13; counter ++) {

    if (counter < 11) {

        System.out.println("Question #" + counter);

            int firstNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);

            int secondNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);

            int intOperatorSymbol = (int)(Math.random()*4);
// Be carefull Here -> Math.random return 0 to 0.9999... so if you don't do that, tou never will get 3


// operator String


            String operatorSymbol = null; 
            int correct = 0;

                switch(intOperatorSymbol)
                {
                    case 0:
                        operatorSymbol = "+";
                        correct = firstNumber+secondNumber;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        operatorSymbol = "-";
                        correct = firstNumber-secondNumber;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        operatorSymbol = "*";
                        correct = firstNumber*secondNumber;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        operatorSymbol = "/";
                        correct = firstNumber/secondNumber;
                        break;
                }

//main arguments


        System.out.println(firstNumber + " " + operatorSymbol + " " + secondNumber);

        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userAnswer = userInputScanner.next();

        int userInt = Integer.parseInt(userAnswer);
        if(userInt == correct)
            System.out.println("right var here");
        else
            System.out.println("wrong var here");



    } else if (counter > 11) {



// last printed line


        System.out.println("Your total score is var here");

        System.out.println(correctAnswer);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Also, I'll give you some infomrations about Java : 
Math.rando return 0 to 0.9999... so if you don't do that, tou never will get 3
A float is not a really precise nubmer, so if you do :

```
float a = 0;
System.out.println(a==0);
```

It would write you false because a is not equal to 0 it's more like 0.00188458 or -0.000512 ore something like that.